# Issue with Caracas time zone in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am testing different time zones UTC offsets in application. And finally this code is properly working almost with all timezones. But i have an issue with Caracas.

Code that shows UTC offset.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];

//This NSDateFormatter will return timezone in format "UTC+XX:XX"
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"'UTC'xxxxx"];

NSString *formattedTimeZone = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

return formattedTimeZone;
```

In Ukraine i receive UTC+03:00 and it is correct. In Caracas i receive UTC-04:00 but real offset is UTC-04:30.

Question is why i am missing -30 minutes in Caracas?

Comment: It will help this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a programming problem, Caracas(Venezuela) timezone has changed recently.

**UTC-04:00 is correct right now.**

Presidents of Venezuela had changed this a couple of times:

- UTC-04:30 was used since 2007.
- It was recently changed again to UTC-04:00.

http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-04-14/maduro-orders-time-zone-change-to-battle-venezuela-power-crisis

Comment: So on other platforms such as android and win phone i am receiving -04:30

Comment: Yeah, knonw issue on several platforms.